# How to Add a Controller in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-mvc

I have created a new Spring MVC 3 project using NetBean. But there is no option of adding a new controller in the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Well adding a Controller is as simple as adding a class annotated with

```
@Controller
```

And specifying the package to be scanned from applicationContext.xml which in turn is specified in the web.xml. Something like this:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

in web.xml

Then in /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />
```

Of course you need the actual schema in your applicationContext.xml

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

And under schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

And then a class :

```
package your.package
.....
@Controller
MyController{

   .....
```

Comment: @user960567 you will have to provide more code. When does this happen? Could you post the web.xml; applicationContext.xml and the Controller?

Comment: This is brand new Spring MVC 3 projects. Can you tell how to show controller in Projects bar

Comment: I really think you are using the wrong IDE now, you should be using SpringSource Tool Suite (a fancy Eclipse), much more suited for Spring Projects.

Comment: OK, Thanks. But in another project NetBeans works with spring.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an annotation driven implementation of Spring you don't need to do anything special.  Create a standard Java class inside the package that Spring is configured to scan.  Then annotate the class with `@Controller` then create your method(s) and mappings using `@RequestMapping`.

In its simplest form a controller would be something like:

```
@Controller
public class MyClass {

  @RequestMapping("/myUrlMapping.do")
  public ModelAndView myMethod() {
    return new ModelAndView("myView");
  }
}
```

This assumes you already have Spring configured correctly.

Comment: The default Spring page works. Then I have created a controller at NetBeansProjects\MYProject\src\MYProject\Controller\MyController.java. I am getting this error. ClassNotFoundException: Documents.Controller.MyController

Comment: Where does the "Documents.Controller" package come from?  Based on your source path it should be "MyProject.Controller".  Find where you referenced the wrong package and fix.  Also, why aren't you using standard Java naming conventions?  (myproject.controller)